# Aussprache von »Libyen«

Tags: pronunciation

Warum wird von vielen Menschen das Wort »*Libyen*« ausgesprochen, als würde man es »*Lybien*« oder »*Lübien*« schreiben?

---

Wikipedia und Wiktionary sind sich einig: Für den Namen des nordafrikanischen Staates Libyen gibt es drei verschiedene Aussprachevarianten, der Duden nennt nur zwei Versionen:

1. [ˈliːby̆ən] (»li« wie in »**Lie**be«, »bü« wie in »**Bü**schel« und »en« wie in »sing**en**«)
2. [ˈliːbi̯ən] (In der Mitte: »bi« wie in »**Bi**nde«, sonst wie in 1)
3. [ˈlyːbi̯ən] (nicht im Duden) (»lü« wie in »**Lü**ge«, sonst wie in 2)

Das Österreichische Wörterbuch (ÖWB) kennt nur die Version 1, und das ist auch jene Version, die in meiner Schule als die einzig richtige gelehrt wurde. Sie stimmt auch ganz mit dem überein, was ich aufgrund der Schreibweise ohnehin erwarten würde.

Auch die Variante 2 kann ich noch nachvollziehen, weil das Y im Deutschen zwar meist wie ein Ü ausgesprochen wird (z.B in »Ypsilon«, »System« und »Typ«), in einigen Fällen aber auch wie ein I (z.B. in »Pony«, »Baby«, »Ybbs«; ein Fluss und eine Stadt in Österreich).

Ich höre aber z.B. in Nachrichtensendungen sehr häufig die Variante 3. Hier wird das I wie ein Ü ausgesprochen, aber das Y wie ein I. Letzteres (Y wie I) kann ich ja noch einigermaßen nachvollziehen (siehe oben), aber aus welchem Grund spricht man hier das I wie ein Ü aus?

**Meine Fragen:**

- Warum hat es sich eingebürgert, das Wort »*Libyen*« auszusprechen, als würde man es »*Lybien*« oder »*Lübien*« schreiben?
- Gibt es andere Wörter, in denen der Buchstabe I als [y] (also wie ein Ü) ausgesprochen wird?
- Warum sagt niemand [ˈlyːby̆ən] (zweimal Ü, kein I)?

Ich glaube übrigens nicht, dass es sich hier um regionale Variationen handelt, lasse mich aber gerne vom Gegenteil belehren. Denn obwohl das ÖWB nur eine Version erlaubt, hört man auch in Österreich alle drei Versionen ungefähr gleich häufig, vielleicht sogar mir einer etwas größeren Häufigkeit der hier thematisierten Variante [ˈlyːbi̯ən], die ja nicht einmal im Dudens steht.

Das Phänomen erscheint mir auch nicht neu zu sein. Ich höre [ˈlyːbi̯ən] schon seit Jahrzehnten.

Comment: @Jan: Ich kann auch keine Belege dafür finden, dass die erste Silbe in irgend einer anderen Sprache als Deutsch als [y] ausgesprochen wird.

Comment: Vermutlich eine falsche Analogie zu den vielen Namen mit …ien: Abchasien, Abessinien, Albanien, Algerien, Anatolien, Andalusien, Antiochien, Äolien, Apulien, Aquitanien, Arabien, Aragonien, Argentinien, Arkadien, Armenien, Asien, Assyrien, Asturien, Äthiopien, Ätolien, Australien usw.

Comment: @Loong *(As)syrien* ist darunter übrigens das interessanteste, denn das hat im Griechischen die Endung *-ία* und ein *y* vorne im Wort.

Comment: @Loog: Das ist ein sehr interessanter und plausibler Ansatz. Kannst du da mehr dazu finden, und eventuell eine Antwort daraus machen?

Comment: @Loong: Halt! Mir fällt gerade auf, dass dein Ansatz nur die Variante 2 erklärt. Meine Frage galt aber der Variante 3, also dem I, das wie ein Ü ausgesprochen wird. Dafür liefern deine Beispiele leider keinen Anhaltspunkt.

Comment: Eine Lautverwechslung mit *Lykien*, vielleicht? (Da war doch ein Land, das hieß irgendwie so?)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Das Wort *Libyen* entstammt – wie viele andere Bezeichnungen für Gebiete des östlichen Mittelmeerraums – dem Altgriechischen; dort wird die ensprechende Gegend *Λιβύη (Libýe)* geschrieben. Über das Lateinische ist diese Bezeichnung wie viele andere aus diese Gegend *(Αἴγυπτος (Aígyptos), Ἀσσυρία (Assyría), Κύπρος (Kýpros))* ins Deutsche gekommen. Früher wurde ein solches *y* im Deutschen zwar – wie im nachklassischen Latein oder in den romanischen Sprachen – als /i/ ausgesprochen, doch im Lauf des 19. Jahrhunderts wurde die Aussprache /y/ eingeführt. Die »klassische« Aussprache wäre demnach die erste ([ˈliːby̆ən]) – was auch erklärt, warum dir diese in der Schule als die einzig richtige beigebracht wurde.

Der Laut /y/<sup>[1]</sup> und insbesondere der Unterschied zum Laut /u/ war nicht in der indogermanischen Ursprache präsent; diese kannte laut den Angaben von [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indogermanische_Ursprache#Phonologie_und_Phonetik) nur fünf Vokalphoneme (sowie Diphthonge). Daher weisen auch die meisten indogermanischen Sprachen ebenjene fünf Vokalphoneme auf, beziehungsweise unterscheiden mindestens diese fünf. Gerundete Vorderzungenvokale wie /ø/ und /y/ treten in Europa etwa in den germanischen oder in den gallo-romanischen Sprachen im Kontrast zu den entsprechenden gerundeten Hinterzungenvokalen wie /o/ und /u/ auf. Oft sind sie aus den entsprechenden Hinterzungenvokal durch Lautwandel entstanden, teils durch spontanen Lautwandel (so zum Beispiel im Altgriechischen oder im Französischen, wo jedes /u/ zu einem /y/ wurde), teil durch kombinatorischen Lautwandel (so zum Beispiel im Althochdeutschen, wo mit dem i-Umlaut ein /u/ genau dann zu einem /y/ wurde, wenn in der nächsten Silbe ein /i/ folgte).

Es ist also selbstverständlich für das Altgriechische, dass dort /y/ an jeder Stelle des Wortes auftreten kann; schließlich war es ein vollwertiges Vokalphonem. Gleiches könnte man auch für das Deutsche und die anderen germanischen Sprachen erwarten, in denen die Unterscheidung /i/ – /y/ – /u/ im Laufe des Sprachwandels erst phonemisch wurde. Die gerundeten Vordervokale sind Umlaute – das ist nicht nur ein schöner Name, sondern bezeichnet auch ihre Herkunft. Ein /i/-Laut in der Folgesilbe sorgte dafür, dass die entsprechenden hinteren Vokale /u/, /o/ oder /a/ nach vorne; in Richtung /i/ umgelautet wurden. Dies geschah vor Allem in Stammsilben, weswegen in deutschen Stammwörtern Umlaute auch in der Regel in der (betonten) Stammsilbe auftreten. Der Umlaut wurde erst phonemisch, als das Umlaut-auslösende /i/ oder der entsprechende Laut im Laufe des Sprachwandels schwand, und schließlich nur noch der umgelautete Vokal blieb um Silben auseinanderzuhalten *(blute/Blüte).*

Für deutschsprachige Zungen ist es üblich, /y/ in *betonten* Silben vorzufinden, allerdings sehr unüblich, diesen Laut in Silben zu finden, die nicht betont werden. Dies liegt daran, dass das Deutsche eine Wortsprache mit starkem dynamischen Akzent ist. Die Vokale der betonten Silben unterscheiden sich in ihrer Aussprache von denjenigen der unbetonten Silben. Nur in den betonten Silben sind die Vokale voll differenziert. Der Nebentonvokalismus hingegen ist reduziert. Die Vokale der unbetonten Silben zeigen eine starke Tendenz zur Reduktion, die letztlich im Schwa [ə] endet. Das Wort *Libyen* widersetzt sich dieser Tendenz: Hier müsste die /y/-Silbe die unbetonte Nebensilbe sein. Das ist für deutschsprachige Zungen ungewohnt und daher schwierig. Im Griechischen, im Französischen oder auch im nicht-indogermanischen Finnischen ist das nicht so. Diese Sprachen sind nicht Wortsprachen, sondern Silbensprachen. Sie haben nicht einen dynamischen, sondern einen musikalischen oder quantitativen Akzent. In den nicht akzentuierten Silben treten also dieselben Vokale auf wie in den akzentuierten. /u/ und /y/ können ohne Probleme in allen Silben auftreten *(hylly,* Finnisch für *Regal,* hat ein betontes und ein unbetontes /y/, beide sind qualitativ gleich).

Die offensichtlichste Vereinfachung wäre, die Rundung wegfallen zu lassen, dadurch würde aus /y/ ein /i/ – was die zweite Aussprachevariante erklärt, die übrigens auch dem Standard in den romanischen Sprachen, Englisch und Arabisch entspricht (dort überall eine Aussprachevariation von *libia,* d.h. ausschließlich mit dem /i/-Laut). Auch im Deutschen war dies die normale Aussprache, bevor für griechisches *y* wieder die Aussprache /y/ eingeführt wurde, und bis heute ist die Aussprache mit /i/ im Deutschen verbreitet. Dass hierbei zwei altgriechische Phoneme zusammenfallen ist unwichtig, denn das Wort bleibt trotzdem eindeutig. (Und auch im modernen Neugriechischen ist /y/ an vielen wenn nicht allen Stellen mit /i/ zusammengefallen.) Gleiches passiert übrigens in vielen anderen griechischen Lehnwörtern mit *y,* wie *Polymér.* Man beachte den Unterschied zu *Polýpen,* das scheinbar gleich aussieht, wo das *y* betont ist. *Polymer* kenne ich ausgesprochen ausschließlich mit /i/ in der mittleren Silbe, während ich *Polypen* nur mit /y/ kenne. Weitere Beispiele sind Wörter wie *Brille, Gips* oder *Silbe,* in denen die Aussprache mit /i/ sogar in die Schreibung übernommen wurde, obwohl ein griechisches *y* zugrunde liegt (vgl. *Beryll* oder englisch *gypsum, syllable),* oder Wörter wie *Zylinder* oder *Ägypten,* wo sogar Siebs noch die Aussprache mit /i/ vorschrieb, während heute die Aussprache mit /y/ üblicher geworden ist.

Bleibt nun noch die dritte Variante. Sie erscheint mir eine Art Hyperkorrektur. Etymologisch ist sie nicht sinnvoll und auch rein lautlich sollte *Li-bi-en* näher liegen als *Lü-bi-en.* Dass sie verwendet wird, steht außer Frage. Zu diesem Phänomen schreibt Stefan Kleiner:<sup>[2]</sup>

> [D]ie Aussprache des Ländernamens *Libyen* [stellt] einen Spezialfall [dar], für den alle Kodizes – ähnlich wie bei *Embryo* – unsilbisches [y] in der Nebensilbe fordern (DAW: [Aussprachevariante 1]. Unser Korpusbefund zeigt, dass diese Variante nur auf 4% [sic] der Belege kommt, bei den allermeisten besteht eine Art [y]-Metathese ([Aussprachevariante 3]), d.h. das [y] wird in seine „natürliche“ Position in der Tonsilbe verschoben.

Die dritte Aussprachevariante entstünde also dadurch, dass die Sprecher im Hinterkopf wissen, dass dieses Wort ein /y/ enthalten muss, und unbewusst das /y/ in die (betonte) Erstsilbe verschieben, obgleich dort ein /i/ sein müsste. Man könnte dies auch als »Hyperkorrektur« verstehen: Irgendwo muss ein /y/ sein und es ist natürlicher, es in die erste Silbe zu setzen.

---

**Anmerkung und Quelle:**

[1]: Ich treffe hier bewusst und explizit *keine* Unterscheidung zwischen dem kurzen und dem langen Vokal /y/ beziehungsweise /yː/, wiewohl diese selbstverständlich verschiedene Phoneme darstellen. Es darf davon ausgegangen werden, dass kurzes und langes *ü* durch parallele Entwicklung entstanden sind.

[2]: Stefan Kleiner: [*Die Kodifikation der deutschen Standardaussprache im Spiegel der faktischen Variabilität des Gebrauchsstandards.*](https://ids-pub.bsz-bw.de/files/3564/Kleiner_Kodifikation_der_deutschen_Standardaussprache_2014.pdf) In: Albrecht Plewnia, Andreas Witt (Herausgeber): *Sprachverfall?. Dynamik — Wandel — Variation.* Walter de Gruyter, Berlin/Boston 2014 (Institut für Deutsche Sprache (Mannheim): Jahrbuch; 2013, ISSN 0537-7900), ISBN 978-3-11-034291-8, Seite 290.

Comment: Ausgezeichnete und höchst interessante Antwort! Ich hätte dir gerne zweimal +1 gegeben, aber das geht leider nicht. An der historischen Entwicklung der Vokale (allgemein, und speziell im Deutschen) habe ich sehr großes Interesse. Mich würde ja auch sehr interessieren, warum ausgerechnet Deutsch so viele verschiedene Vokale enthält.

Comment: +1 Sehr interessant, danke! --- "...Umlaute auch in der Regel ausschließlich in der (betonten) Stammsilbe auftreten": wie sieht es mit _Reichtümer_, _ungestüm_ und _Ungetüm_ aus? Sind sie Grund, das "ausschließlich" aus Deinem Satz zu streichen?

Comment: @Matthias *ungestüm* hat zwei Vorsilben, von denen eine die Betonung an sich zieht; das ist bei anderen Wörtern auch der Fall also eher nicht. Ähnlich wäre *Ungetüm* meines Erachtens. *Reichtümer* ist interessanter; da ist es ja die Nachsilbe, die einen Umlaut erhält. Allerdings ließe sich das auch so erklären, dass die Nachsilbe ein eigenes Morphem darstellt, das somit nochmals eine Nebenbetonung ins Wort mit einbringt … Trotzdem schadet es bestimmt nicht, das *ausschließlich* zu streichen, schließlich beißt es sich sowieso ein bisschen mit *in der Regel* ;)

Answer (score 9):

Ich höre fast nur Variante 3, deren Popularität sich meines Erachtens so begründet:

> Variante 1 ist ein Zungenbrecher.

Ferner: Je populärer Variante 3 ist, umso mehr Menschen glauben an die Schreibung »Lybien« und nutzen Variante 3 dann schon alleine deshalb.

Answer (score 2):

Zu Frage 1:

Auch wenn den meisten Deutschsprachlern wohl bewusst ist, dass **y** im Deutschen sowohl wie **ü** als auch wie **i** klingen kann, gehen vermutlich viele davon aus, dass man einen Unterschied zwischen den beiden verschiedenen Buchstaben **y** und **i** im selben Wort hören sollte, da man ansonsten den selben Buchstaben hätte verwenden können. Die Präsenz des **i** bedingt in diesem Fall gewissermaßen die Aussprache des "y" als **ü**.

Der Rest ergibt sich aus unserer auf Leseerfahrung beruhenden Wahrnehmung. Wir lesen nicht die einzelnen Buchstaben, sondern erfassen ein Wort als Ganzes. Der folgende Text wird dies veranschaulichen:
[image]

Da die Aussprache **Lib*ü*en** sehr mühsam ist, das Wort aber sowohl den Laut **i** als auch den Laut **ü** beinhalten soll, hat sich in der Sprachpraxis das deutlich leichter zu sprechende **L*ü*bien** weithin eingebürgert. Die Positionen von **i** und **y** werden also kurzerhand vertauscht.

Zu Frage 2:

Ich keine keine weiteren Fälle, in denen **i** wie **ü** gesprochen wird bzw. in denen ein vergleichbarer *Postitionstausch* im Transfer vom geschriebenen zum gesprochenen Wort vorgenommen wird.

Zu Frage 3:

Da das **i** nicht als **ü** gelesen wird, gibt es die Option **L*ü*b*ü*en** nicht.