# Ist »Xyphoid« eine korrekte Alternative zu »Xiphoid«?

Tags: spelling, technical-terminology, loanword, greek

Es geht um das [Xiphoid](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brustbein) (Schwertfortsatz in medizinischer Fachsprache).

Ist *Xyphoid* – was ich in meinem Beruf oft sehe – eine korrekte Alternative zu *Xiphoid?*

Meistens wird es mit *i* geschrieben. Auch die meisten offiziellen Quellen ([Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brustbein)) sowie die latenische Schreibweise ist mit *i.* Im Duden finde ich nichts.

Comment: Meines Erachtens nicht. Das (alt-)griechische i und y stellen zwei unterschiedliche Vokale dar, ausgesprochen vereinfacht i und ü. Damit ist xiphos ein Schwert und xyphos (= "xüfos") gibt es nicht.

Comment: Wahrscheinlich so ein Fall wie das häufig so ausgesprochene "Mykrometer" (eigtl. von _mikrós_). Wobei sich aber andererseits, zumindest nach meinem Eindruck, "Oxid" gegen "Oxyd" (von _oxýs_) durchgesetzt hat... zumindest in der Nicht-Fachsprache.

Comment: Hier geht es doch um Altgriechisch, oder sehe ich das falsch? Was hat diese Frage in einem Deutsch-Forum zu suchen? Dieselbe Frage könnte man doch genau so gut oder genau so schlecht auch in einem Englisch- Spanisch- oder Französisch-Forum stellen.

Comment: @hubert Es mag sich um ein Fremdwort altgriechischen Ursprungs handeln, aber meine Frage bezieht sich immer noch auf die Schreibweise im Deutschen.

Comment: @phg, wahrscheinlich weil es auch andere -ide gibt: Fluorid, Cynanid, usw. Soweit ich weiß, bevorzugt der Duden Oxid, und auch die Chemiker.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Meines Erachtens ist "Xyphoid" **keine** korrekte Alternative.

Das (alt-)griechische i (Iota) und y (Ypsilon) stellen zwei unterschiedliche Vokale dar, die vereinfacht dargestellt als i bzw. ü ausgesprochen werden. Die Herkunft des medizinischen Fachausdrucks ist tatsächlich das Schwert, was auf griechisch "**xiphos**" heißt und (in etwa) "xifoss" ausgesprochen wird.

Das Wort "*xyphos*" hingegen (das "xüfoss" ausgesprochen würde) gibt es so weit ich sehe im Griechischen nicht. Und deshalb ist es auch keine korrekte Alternative zum Schwert.

*Eine exzellente, ausführliche Erläuterung zum griechischen i und y findet sich übrigens in [einer Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/34738/aussprache-von-libyen) auf die Frage zur Aussprache von Libyen.*

Andererseits gibt es natürlich sehr wohl griechische Wörter mit "xy", zum Beispiel "**xylon**" (zu deutsch Holz), das auch "xülon" ausgesprochen wird. Deshalb ist vermutlich "Xyphoid" eine Art falsche Analogie, bei der davon ausgegangen wird, dass griechisch "xi" und "xy" das Gleiche seien. Wie in den Kommentaren angemerkt, findet sich dieses Phänomen auch bei anderen Wörtern mit griechischen Wortbestandteilen wie beispielsweise "Mikrometer", das auch manchmal fälschlicherweise "Mykrometer" ausgesprochen wird.

Comment: Es mag sich aus der [angelsächsischen Literatur](https://scholar.google.de/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=%22xyphoid%22&btnG=) eingeschlichen haben und das, obwohl es auch dort *xiphoid* gibt.

Comment: @Takkat. Laut Oxford English Dictionary is "xyphoid" ein Fehler ("erron,") fuer "xiphoid".

Comment: @fdb im Englischen irrtümliche aber doch alternative und deshalb nicht unbedingt falsche Schreibweise, die [schon im 17. Jahrhundert belegt ist](https://books.google.de/books?id=U08PAAAAYAAJ&dq=xyphoid&pg=RA2-PA368#v=onepage&q=xyphoid&f=false) und zumindest erklärt, warum man das nun auch bei uns findet.

Comment: @Takkat. Die falsche Schreibung ξύφος findet sich eigentlich bereits im byzantinischen Etymologicum Magnum (12. Jht), auf Grund einer falschen Ableitung vom Verbum ξύω.

Answer (score 0):

Kleiner Nachtrag: Im Duden Wörterbuch Medizinischer Fachbegriffe ist kein Wort gelistet, das "xyphoid" enthält, xiphoid kommt aber mehrmals vor. Ich interpretiere in Kombination mit der Antwort von IQV davon aus, dass xyhpoid falsch ist.